# jquery onSubmit() problems after returning data from php

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, validation

I am trying to validate my forms by using jQuery and php .. What I am trying to achieve is pass my form inputs to process.php in the background, check if inputs pass my validation code, then return true or false back to my jQuery checkForm() function .. so far the below code is now working ..

```js
function checkForm() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "process.php",
    data: {
      reguser: $("#reguser").val(),
      regpass: $("#regpass").val(),
      regpass2: $("#regpass2").val(),
      regemail: $("#regemail").val()
    },
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {}
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```html
<form action="register.php" method="post" onSubmit="return checkForm()">
```

Comment: please read http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: what's the error that you are getting ?

Comment: try to call your function checkForm() in submit handler of validation.

Comment: @GaurangSondagar .. I don't actually get any errors .. The page submits to register.php even with errors.

Comment: @Apoorva The page still submits to register.php even with errors ..

Comment: which errors are you getting? can you post your jquery validation code?

Answer (score 0):

send all input's in php to validate all the data.

```
function checkForm() {
  $.ajax({
    url : "process.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: $('#yourForm').serialize(),
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data)
    {
      if(data.status)
      {
        alert("Success"); 
      }
      else
      {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.inputerror.length; i++) 
        {
          alert(data.inputerror[i] + "|" +  data.error_string[i]);
        }
      }
    }
  });
};
```

validating the data you've sent through Ajax.

```
  public function process()
  {
    $this->_validate_all_data();
    echo json_encode(array("status" => true));
  }

  private function _validate_all_data()
  {
    $data = array();
    $data['error_string'] = array();
    $data['inputerror'] = array();
    $data['status'] = true;

    if(empty($POST['reguser']))
    {
      $data['inputerror'][] = 'reguser'; // input name
      $data['error_string'][] = 'Reguser is required'; // message for validation
      $data['status'] = false;
    }

    if($data['status'] === false)
    {
      echo json_encode($data);
      exit();
    }
  }
```

Comment: I don't think this is what I want. All I want is to activate onSubmit() to prevent the form from being submitted if it fails my validation script (process.php) .. I wrote my process.php to give return either true or false. I just need to use that output to either make submit active or inactive.